# Offset a Point and return self with an Extension

Tags: c#

It is possible to offset a Point like this?
With this extension I was unable to achieve it.

I like using chain methods like:
p1.Add(new Point(1, 0)).Round().RotateAround(p2, 45).Etc...
And with current offset method provided by Point struct are not possible.Because the offset method not return self as instance.

```
var p1 = new Point(1, 2);
Console.WriteLine("Before p1:{0}", p1);
// p1+=new Point(1, 0);
p1.Add(new Point(1, 0));
Console.WriteLine("After p1:{0}", p1);

// out
Before p1:{ X = 1,Y = 2}
After p1:{ X = 1,Y = 2} // should be { X = 2,Y = 2} 

// Extension
public static Point Add(this Point p, Point offset) {
  p.X += offset.X;
  p.Y += offset.Y;
  return p;
}
```

Comment: You don't need an extension method. The `Point` structure already has an `Offset` method that works exactly like that. You should already know that because you should have read the documentation for the `Point` structure before asking the question.

Comment: Yes yes, I know the offset method. It may not be clear what I want to achieve. The offset method does indeed change the position of the point, but it does not return itself. You cannot then use chaining like p1.Add(new Point(1, 0)).Round().RotateAround(p2, 45).Etc...

Comment: "With this extension I was unable to achieve it." - So what happens with your current code? (And what does this have to do with csharpcodeprovider?) It would also be very helpful if you could specify *exactly* which Point type you mean, given that there are multiple ones available.

Comment: I'm using Point from .NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Drawing.dll. The problem with code is that original value of point (p1) is not changed after apply .Add(new Point(1, 0))

Comment: *"It may not be clear what I want to achieve"*. Not, it wasn't, because you never actually explained it.

Comment: Sorry, I was hoping it would be clear from the example given. My mistake, I hope it's clearer now sir.

Comment: Examples are just to demonstrate a principle. You still need to explain that principle. ALWAYS provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation.

Answer (score 1):

No matter whether it's an extension method or not, if you have a value-type parameter and you want to modify it inside the method and have that change reflected outside the method, you need to declare that parameter `ref`:

```cs
public static class PointExtensions
{
    public static Point Add(this ref Point source, Point offset)
    {
        source.Offset(offset);

        return source;
    }
}
```

The other code you have will now work as you want.

Comment: on provided example worked fine.

Comment: I have trouble to implement it in my code:
where I got error A property or indexer may not be passed as an out or ref parameter.
 d.TStartLocalPos.Add(new Point(1, 0));
// property is called from control
```
internal class SplineDot : UserControl {
....
public Point TStartLocalPos { get; set; }
```

Comment: @Orien, the issue is that you are trying to use a value-type property. A property is backed by a field and the property getter returns a copy of that field value. That means that passing the property to a `ref` parameter would be modifying that copy rather than the underlying field, so it would look like it was changing the property value when it actually wasn't. That is not specific to your question at all. It's the way value types work so there's nothing you can do about it. You cannot pass a value-type property directly to a `ref` parameter. Assign it to a variable first and use that.

Comment: I'm not so skilled with comments yet, here is screen then ![](https://cestaslunce.cz/scripts/shared/2023-03-11_13h51_04.png)